# Designing a UI for Programmers to Use

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface, photoshop

I am doing UI design for a group of programmers who are working on building music-related software. I have created .psd files for all of the mockups, graphics, etc.

I was assuming they just needed the (many) images to put into the code, but they want me to use a GUI to spit out the necessary code. (I looked at [Antetype](http://www.antetype.com), but it just seems so basic compared to my Photoshop mockups.)

**My question:** Is there a GUI tool that can build VERY UNIQUE designs, and can export the mockups in code using MatLab or Java? -- Or should I just say no and give them the images to use in the code. (we are talking guitar-pedal knobs, EQ sliders, etc.)

Comment: Will they be using this software via the web or just as an application on their desktop/laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has a decent swing WYSIWYG editor for Java GUIs that's certainly worth looking into. There's going to be some significant back-end work getting your graphics to look just right if you have particular/complex designs in mind, but that said customizing Java GUI's is much easier than MATLAB. . . I believe eclipse also has plug ins available for this same sort of thing.

Anyways, that is probably the closest you'll get to a nice drag-n-drop interface in Java for GUI design.

JFace is also a pretty spectacular framework that sits atop SWT for building Java GUI's. I would say that it's power lies in how it handles different windows/components, but of course the trade off is that it's more complicated to put together (no WYSIWYG that I know of)

Also consider the Microsoft route, Visual Studio is designed to take the pain out of layout designs in writing Visual Basic/C#/.net applications. If you're a student your university probably has a deal to get you a free copy (mine did) otherwise visual studio express should be free (I think? ...citation needed?)

Answer (score 1):

To create a UI you can use some tools, Netbeans in first .. but i think that is better to create a consistent code using simple layout and component, so doing it by hand ([Oracle interesting tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)). If you aren't a java programmer i suggest you can simply give them your image.